# Suggest another stack exchange site while closing

Tags: feature-request

While reviewing close votes some times  there are some questions that belong to other other Stack Exchange sites or communities such as https://gaming.stackexchange.com/.

Is there a way to suggest questions to be migrated to sites that are not in the *migrate to list* ?

### Migrate to List

[image]

Comment: Eventually, this may come: [Make migration paths just another Off Topic reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215054/make-migration-paths-just-another-off-topic-reason) — but don't hold your breath.

Comment: You do know that a moderator can migrate to any site, right? It's only close votes and recommend closure flags that are restricted to the five sites.

Comment: @slhck I did realize that development of this feature would not be the top priority ( I pictured a younger me going to my PM with a feature that would be 'cool' and him shaking his head while patting my back)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use a custom flag to request a mod move a post. You may not get it, but thats the right way to. As always, make sure the question is worth saving, and is on topic before requesting migration, and I do believe the same age limitation on user migrations counts for mod migrations too.

Comment: But please remember... DO NOT MIGRATE CRAP!

Comment: Agree, but also, it is not the case that every possible English interrogative sentence ending in a question can be answered on a StackExchange site. There are some (many...) questions that are simply off-topic *everywhere*.

Comment: I believe thats implicit in my answer, in both cases. A non-standard migration request should be no different from a standard one.

Answer (score 6):

Each site can have up to 5 migration targets, 1 of which must be that site's own meta. All of Super User's migration targets are currently in use. Gaming.SE used to be an option, but we found that Android.SE was getting more migrations (manually made by moderators) than Gaming was even with Gaming as a default option, so Android was added as a default and Gaming was taken out.

You can always flag with the "other..." reason and ask for a question to be migrated, but remember, if the question is valid on Super User, don't vote to migrate it even if it's also valid elsewhere.